# Complete swipe UIScrollView paging enabled action

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have `UIScrollView` with paging enabled so user can swipe my subviews which contain `UIImageView`.

Right now, I use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView` but it also called before my image in `UIScrollView` changed. Even if I just touch, 'semi-swipe', and still in current image, that method is called.

My question is, how to get action when user is completely swipe my `UIScrollView`?

Comment: scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is called when the scroll of your scroll view comes to halt ... which mean until it doesn't completely stopped and this is the right place to do anything after your completely scrolled to next view . for reference you check this apple's doucmentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating?language=objc)

Comment: But if I swipe a litle then release it, this is also get called. Even though, my scrollView didn't change its page.

Comment: Do you put your action method in it ?? Does it calling it multiple times ?? because i have implemented the similar thing a week before and it's working for me just fine

Comment: You could try to store the current position (or offset) of your scrollview, and if that `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` function is called, you check if the position (or offset) is different to the previous one. If yes, the user has scrolled.